# SSL Certificate Error on stackapps.com

Tags: feature-request, ssl, 404-not-found, stackapps, subdomains

When checking to see if there is a meta for stackapps.com I found out that there is none (and a [different Panda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/didZS.jpg) photo than I'm used to seeing). Also there's an **SSL certificate error**. This is probably a low priority or *curiosity*, but I thought I'd mention it. Previously such problems have been described as an oversight, and corrected.

Similar to the question: "[Stacksnippets has the incorrect SSL certificate :(](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263383/stacksnippets-has-the-incorrect-ssl-certificate)" I am reporting what seems to be described by Qualys as: "The domain name is an alias for a web site whose main name is different, but the **alias was not included in the certificate by mistake**.". The main site comes back as "[A+](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=stackapps.com)" for four separate IP addresses.

When *cleverly* redirecting the errant URL it leads to a webpage that apparently could have been (but wasn't) included in the certificate. The Qualys [test URL is here](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=meta.stackapps.com), for what it's worth to include it in the question (security report). Google, for example, doesn't do this clever trick; if I try to visit nosuchplace.google.com my browser simply says it can't connect, Google doesn't bother redirecting such errant URLs.

Perhaps it would be cost saving (for certificates) and easier to maintain if the redirection was to a webpage on the main site (for example) explaining that some sites don't have an associated meta site.

Apparently this could be resolved by having a [wildcard certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) or [Subject Alternative Name (SAN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) if you wanted to keep everything as-is, but repair the certificate error.

Note: The Q&A: "[Wildcard SSL Cert producing error on Facebook.Stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120104/wildcard-ssl-cert-producing-error-on-facebook-stackoverflow-com)" (from 2012) is marked as [a dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites) of a duplicate: "[Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time)" which says https works network-wide. Thus, I feel this report is not a duplicate of that Q&A; and worth mentioning.

Comment: Meta questions for Stackapps are posted right on its main site with the [meta] tag.

Comment: @Laurel - does this not apply to more than one site, and thus can be posted on main?

Comment: @animuson - Apparently [certificate errors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295359/why-is-https-meta-dev-superuser-com-indexed-by-google) occur on our sites from time to time.